# Change datatype of register being watched from unsigned to signed in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, assembly, watch, cpu-registers

I'm writing an assembly program in Visual Studio 2017, and I'm watching the values of the registers Ax, Bx, and Cx as I step through the program. The values are represented as unsigned shorts, which is a problem when the values become negative. I was wondering if there is a way to show these values as signed shorts.

[Cx is shown as 65529, but the signed representation is supposed to be -7.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBH9Y.png)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, by using that a watch can be an *expression*, even if it involves [pseudovariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/pseudovariables?view=vs-2017).

For example, adding `(short)$cx` as a watch lets you view the value of `cx` interpreted as a (signed) short.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**View register value for Signed and Unsigned data in Watch Window of Visual Studio**

Examples of 8-bit Registers:

- (signed char)$AL
- (unsigned char)$AH

Examples of 16-bit Registers:

- (signed short)$AX
- (unsigned short)$CX

Examples of 32-bit Registers:

- (signed int)$ESI
- (unsigned int)$EDI

[image]

And for 64-bit mode:

- (signed long)$RAX
- (unsigned long)$RBX

[image]

Reference: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm#:~:text=the%20upcoming%20chapters.-,Integer%20Types,-The%20following%20table](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm#:%7E:text=the%20upcoming%20chapters.-,Integer%20Types,-The%20following%20table)